# How to mock method returning istream&?

Tags: c++, c++11, googlemock, istream

I have mocked virtual method returning `istream&`. I'd like to use it in a testcase. How to return some value?

The problem is that `istream` is noncopyable.

I try something like this:

```
TEST(x, y)
{
     MockClass mock;
     std::istringstream str("Some text");

     EXPECT_CALL(mock, m(_)).WillOnce(Return(str)); // m method returns std::istream&

     sut.callMethod();
}
```

Comment: How are you assigning the returned value?

Comment: Tell it its pants are out of fashion.  Can you show what you tried, and what went wrong, in a [MCVE]?

Comment: What exactly the problem you are having? I am assuming compilation error, because in google mock you can't use Return() for references

Comment: can you also add the details of 'sut' object.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should use ReturnRef() instead of Return(). Refer to gmock cheat sheet:

https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/docs/gmock_cheat_sheet.md#returning-a-value

Answer (score 2):

Generally I would simply return a string input stream which I have control over. That way I can push expected values into it. Along these lines:

```
std::istringstream myStream{"This is expected content"};
mocks::MyMockClass mockClass{myStream};
```

Then in your method:

```
std::istream& doTheMockedAction(){
    return myStream;
}
```

EDIT:
For a mocking framework I would expect that you should be able to do something like this (bear in mind I haven't used Google Mocks so I am completely making this up)

```
auto mockOfRealType = MOCK_CLASS<RealType>();
EXPECT_CALL(mockOfRealType, doTheMockedAction()).WillOnce(ReturnRef(myStream))
```

ALSO:
You need to assign it to a reference:

```
std::istream& a = doTheMockedAction();
```

Comment: Thanks, your solution is ok. But I need to return different values. Is it possible to do something like that in inside WillOnce(...)' ? Just to return my std::istringstream` object? For example I want to return defined locally in test: std::istringstream xxx("xxx"). Is it possible?

Comment: @peter55555 I haven't used `gmock` so I can't say for certain but usually a mock framework will allow you to return any sub-class of the returned reference. So for example I would expect you should be allowed to do something along the lines of what I added to the main answer above (see edit)

Comment: @downvoter it is common practise to leave a comment about what you think is wrong with the answer if you are down-voting.